# MVC bind checkbox to invert its meaning

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

In my model class I have a boolean property `DoNotEmail`.

In the UI design I've been given to create a view for, the meaning of the checkbox is inverted; i.e. the label next to the checkbox says `"Send Email"`.

Normally I would add the checkbox like this: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DoNotEmail)` but clearly this is the wrong way round.

Do I need to create a separate view model with a custom property for this checkbox, or is there some clever way I can do something like: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => !model.DoNotEmail)`  (which clearly doesn't work)?

Comment: Is `DoNotEmail` a field from the database? Is your model class an entity or a custom model?

Comment: Yes it's a column in the database and yes the model class is an entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing entities directly to your view is never a good idea, if your DB schema ever changes you would have to go through all your views and update them. I would recommend creating a `ViewModel` and passing only the data required for the view, then map your `DoNotEmail` property in the controller. That way you maintain the abstraction between your model/view and keeps your view simple e.g.

```
public void ViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Send Email")]
    public bool SendEmailNotification { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SendEmailNotifications)
```

**Controller**

```
public void Post(ViewModel model)
{
    var entity = ...;
    entity.DoNotEmail = !model.SendEmailNotification;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks - I'd been only using ViewModels where I had to.  Looks like I should be using them all the time then...

Comment: @Andy I would always recommend a view model, gives you a clean separation. If you find yourself needing to create view models in a lot of places have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks @James.  AutoMapper looks useful.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do it which may be called a work around is that :

Make DontEmail a Hidden value.
And create a Checkbox. Bind jquery event to it and when selected then invert the value of DontEmail. I hope i dont need to put in code to explain this. If required let me know.